# Connect different points with line in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have matrix of 2 column (x and y) and 100 rows, and each row  make one point like (x1,y1).

I need to draw a line consecutively between them, like point (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) and (x2,y2) to (x3,y3) and so on till (x100,y100).

I have written this code and it's working properly. The problem is, it takes too long as I have to do this for 55000 matrix.

```
    figure;
         for j=1:length(data); % data = 55000 different matrices which should draw in the same figure

          for i=1:length(data(j).x);
          x= (data(j).x(i));
          y= (data(j).y(i));

          if i == length(data(j).x);
              break;
          end

          x1= (data(j).x(i+1));
          y1= (data(j).y(i+1));

          line([x,x1],[y,y1]);


  end

end
```

Is there any more efficient and quicker way to do that?

Comment: you can lose the inner loop if you use `line` as in the documentation. There is not much to be done about the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

```
x = [];
y = [];
for j=1:length(data)
    x = [x; data(j).x];
    y = [y; data(j).y];
end
plot(x, y);
```

Comment: I want to connect the x,y points with line to gather. also take a lot of times.

Comment: plot(x, y); should be inside the loop? I have put 'plot' out side of the loop and then ran it. it was working fine. but still its takes long time to go.

Comment: I guess the drawing takes time. Don't know how accurate your drawing needs to be, but maybe you can simplify your lines? I could recommend dpsimplify for that.